# Clone Sheet to new workbook, keep format, remove formula's and clear part of content

Tags: excel, vba

Her also a newbie on VBA.
I have looked at a lot of topics and I could actually find some parts of the solution I’m looking for.
But I can’t see how to combine them in to one VBA.

I have an Excel Workbook that contains information and formula’s on a specific sheet.
I would like to copy that entire sheet to an new ONE sheet Workbook and save it.
The criteria for this new sheet are also:
-   Keep the formatting as is.
-   Remove all formulas (only remain values)
-   Clear data in certain ranges or specific cells
-   The destination sheet doesn’t need to contain macro’s (XLSX file type)
I would like to start this action from the source Sheet by using a shape and assign this to the VBA.
Here is what I found:

Copy sheet to new workbook:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Copy Before:=Workbooks("Example.xlsx").Sheets(1)
```

Copy keep format but remove formulas

```
ActiveSheet.Copy
Cells.Copy
Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Clear cells / ranges:

```
Sub Clearcells()
Range("A2", "A5").Clear
Range("C10", "D18").Clear
Range("B8", "B12").Clear
End Sub
```

(Is it possible also to have the option to add a complete column? Like:

```
Range("B:B").Clear
```

Is there someone who can help me out in combining this into one running VBA?
Thanks, upfront.

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
Public Sub Test()

    Dim wrkbk As Workbook
    Dim rng As Range

    'Create new workbook with single sheet.
    Set wrkbk = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)

    'Copy sheet to new workbook and remove the existing sheet
    'without displaying any confirmation messages.
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Copy Before:=wrkbk.Sheets(1)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wrkbk.Sheets(2).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    'Remove formula, clear contents of cells.
    'ClearContents - remove formula and values from cells.
    With wrkbk.Worksheets(1)
        With .UsedRange
            .Cells.Copy
            .Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        End With
        .Range("A2:A5,C10,D18,B:B").ClearContents
    End With

End Sub
```

Updated code to copy more than one sheet

```
Public Sub Test()

    Dim wrkbk As Workbook
    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    'Create new workbook with single sheet.
    Set wrkbk = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)

    With wrkbk
        'Rename the only sheet so it doesn't clash with those being copied across.
        'Only need to do that if you're going to have a sheet called Sheet1.
        .Worksheets(1).Name = "DELETE ME"

        'Copy the sheets across and then delete the last one.
        'Can either delete by name, or use position of sheet.
        'Worksheet = normal sheet.
        'Sheets = any sheet (chart sheet, worksheet, old style macro sheet).
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")).Copy Before:=.Sheets(1)
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .Worksheets("DELETE ME").Delete
        '--OR--
        '.Sheets(.Sheets.Count).Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End With

    'Remove formula, clear contents of cells.
    'ClearContents - remove formula and values from cells.
    'UsedRange isn't the best way to find the last cell, but is ok for this.
    For Each wrkSht In wrkbk.Worksheets
        With wrkSht
            With .UsedRange
                .Cells.Copy
                .Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
            .Range("A2:A5,C10,D18,B:B").ClearContents
        End With
    Next wrkSht

End Sub
```

Further reading: [With](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/with-statement?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1009555)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue), [ThisWorkbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.thisworkbook)

Comment: This is superb, this work. I'm very happy with your support. Thanks for that.

Comment: Good stuff.  Feel free to tick as accepted answer. :)

Comment: I don’t know if it allowed to ask questions in this topic.
But first question would be.
1. Do I need to close this question as answered? (And if needed, How?)
2. Would it be possible to Copy two sheets for the same workbook, to the new workbook with the same setup (Remove formula’s, keep formatting and clear several cells)
3. I start the VBA, with an shape, the shape is also copied to the new workbook, can this be removed?

Comment: Ticking the answer as accepted closes it, although people can still add answers if they wish - I *think* you can also change the accepted answer if a better one comes along.  It's the accepted way of saying thanks. I've added code to copy over more than one sheet.  As long as your code is a procedure rather than a function and it's public you can right-click the shape and assign a macro to it.  If you wanted to copy the shape & accompanying code to a new workbook I'd probably just make a copy of the current workbook and remove any sheets I didn't want - easier than trying to copy the code over

Comment: Hello Darren, Again super This works for me.Thinking how you want something is one, but see the impact is two :-) The ClearContents range is removing the same content from both two new worksheets. Stupid me, The other tab has other cells that needs to be cleared. Is that also possible? I tried to add two extra lines            Worksheet(“Sheet1”) .Range("A2:A5,C10,D18,B:B").ClearContents
     Worksheet(“Sheet2”) .Range("X8:Y12,F10,G18,L:L").ClearContents but that was to easy thought

Comment: Just add `wrkbk.` at the start of your two new lines and it should work. Not specifying the workbook will use whichever is currently active. Put the two lines after the `Next wrksht` line.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your support and help.
It is working now :-)

I needed to put also some more in the last part of the code:
Like: `With wrkbk` and `End With`
But I looked at your part of the code and tried it, and not it is working.
If it is a proper coding format, I don't know but it is working.
Thanks again.
Full code is now:

```
Public Sub Test()

    Dim wrkbk As Workbook
    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    'Create new workbook with single sheet.
    Set wrkbk = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)

    With wrkbk
        'Rename the only sheet so it doesn't clash with those being copied across.
        'Only need to do that if you're going to have a sheet called Sheet1.
        .Worksheets(1).Name = "DELETE ME"

        'Copy the sheets across and then delete the last one.
        'Can either delete by name, or use position of sheet.
        'Worksheet = normal sheet.
        'Sheets = any sheet (chart sheet, worksheet, old style macro sheet).
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")).Copy Before:=.Sheets(1)
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .Worksheets("DELETE ME").Delete
        '--OR--
        '.Sheets(.Sheets.Count).Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End With

    'Remove formula, clear contents of cells.
    'ClearContents - remove formula and values from cells.
    'UsedRange isn't the best way to find the last cell, but is ok for this.
    For Each wrkSht In wrkbk.Worksheets
        With wrkSht
            With .UsedRange
                .Cells.Copy
                .Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
           '.Range("A2:A5,C10,D18,B:B").ClearContents

        End With
    Next wrkSht
    With wrkbk
        .Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(""A2:A5,C10,D18,B:B"").ClearContents
        .Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("X8:Y12,F10,G18,L:L").ClearContents
    End With
End Sub
```